# collision between player and a limiter is not 100% functional

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

In the game I'm developing, the player moves left and right avoiding obstacles that fall from above, but when the player reaches the left or right limit, a collision bug may occur and he simply leaves the screen. I'm using the `rigidbody.velocity` and the trigger to check for collision but even so, there are times when it manages to cross the wall. Here the script.(And I'm not using `FixedUpdate` because it's not responding well when I tap the screen.)

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isRight;
    public float speed;
    public Transform pointR;
    public Transform pointL;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       

        if(isRight)
        {

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
      
        }

        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
     
        }
         if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
        }

        
        

        

        
       

    
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {

        if(collider.CompareTag("ColisorEs"))
        {
            
            isRight = !isRight;
        }
          if(collider.CompareTag("colisorR"))
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
        }
    }
        
    
        

      
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are 2 colliders one on the left and one on the right and both have the Is Trigger activated, thanks for the answers.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody changes should be handled in the FixedUpdate methode. It's better for Unitys Physics.

You can leave your Input.GetMouseButtonDown in Update.